# wcf wsDualHttpBinding security issues between ASP.NET page and Web service

Tags: asp.net, winforms, wcf, security

I'm completely stuck.

I got a web service on one machine. The web service got two "services" (or binding?) one normal "basicHttpBinding" and one "wsDualHttpBinding". I'm just adding the "wsDualHttpBinding", because I need that a message (a bool) send from a ASP.NET web form is send to my Winforms applications. I have only one user that use the web page, but up to 10 winforms user.

Since I'm reproducing the production environment, I'm stuck: the web page CANNOT connect to the "wsDualHttpBinding" web service. I try many help page, many tutorials, it don't work.

In fact, I think that my issue is that I don't understand why it require any kind of security...

I try to use different "clientCredentialType" but they ALL FAILED.

CLEANER TOPO:

1. Client A: ASP.NET 4.0 webform installed on server AA. When user click a button, it send a bool to the web service 2, propagated to client B.
2. Web service 1: Installed on server BB. Normal basicHttpBinding use to get and update data.
3. Web service 2: In the same projects then web service, on server BB 1. It's a "wsDualHttpBinding" use to send message between Client A and multiples client B. (and between different client B).

   1. Client B: ASP.NET winform. Installed on multiple computer (XP and Seven). In this context, we use it to view message send from Client A.

thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you with "cannot connect" to the endpoint? Does it blew up in run-time? If so, does it give any stacktrace? And how is the sites hosted?

Comment: The web service and the website are self hosted, in an Intranet. Both machines are Windows 2008 R2.
I can give you a stacktrace, BUT I try to many connection method that I'm not sure what is relevant. Does it gonna help you to help me?
I just would like a working example to connect a web page to a wsDualHttpBinding web service. (Winform to the web service seem to work fine)
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be help you please try the below link:--

***http://dotnettechnicalquestion.wordpress.com/interview-questions/net/web-service-and-wcf/***

***http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7062/An-introduction-to-Web-Service-Security-using-WSE***

***http://geekswithblogs.net/nestor/archive/2007/03/06/108042.aspx***

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify binding details of the same in server side configuration file,

have you already done that??

please refer original source [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.aspx)

I hope this may help :)

Comment: I think you did not refer the link,

its for Client and Server Hand Shake and information exchange

you are using for "It's a "wsDualHttpBinding" use to send message between Client A and multiples client B." in point 3 of question.

Please do this using server variable on server, like we do in chat program, not directly with client.

Answer (score 0):

Without more specific details, such as error messages, it's hard to help.  I suggest you add the following to all of your application's config files, as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

This will then give you lots of trace data about exactly what is going on.  I find this really useful in diagnosing WCF issues.